# Column count does not match in DataTable and (databound) DataGridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have been working with `DataGridView` and `DataTable` for long. But I have been unable to identify why/how sometimes(not everywhere) Column count does not match in `DataGridvVew` and `DataTable` even when I have put my `Datatable` as `DataSource` for my `DataGridView`.

```
myGrid.DataSource = myTable;
myGrid.Refresh();
MessageBox.Show(myTable.Columns.Count+"--"+myGrid.Columns.Count);// shows 5--0
```

**Edit:** (In Answer to First Comment) Here my DataTable is being created as

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
myTable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
```

Comment: Could we see how myTable is created in one of the bad cases.

Comment: Yes. Why not. @Mike C. I have shown it.

Comment: Is your DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property  property has true value?

Comment: I tested your code but it seems is correct. the `DataTable` have 3 column and also the `DataGridView` have 3 columns.

Comment: Try myGrid.DataBind() before Refresh

Comment: @SamanGholami. I have tried setting AutoGenerateColumns Property of DataGridView to be true but It did not make any difference.

Comment: I copy your code and run it,it worked!even i clear Refresh() method and it worked too.maybe you have a mistake another place of your code.

Comment: Did you have a predefined columns in your DataGridView? Is it possible that your Mydata DataTable was updated(removed columns)  before printing MessageBox?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I put a DataGridView control in a TabControl.

The DataGridView control was on the second tab of the TabControl and by default it was not shown at startup and when I switched to the second tab I encountered the issue in my implemented DataGridView_CellFormatting event.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TabControl);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue) from Microsoft:

"Controls contained in a TabPage are not created until the tab page is shown, and any data bindings in these controls are not activated until the tab page is shown."

I fixed my issue by adding the following line of code to my Form_Load event:

```
tabControl1.SelectTab(1); //Selects the second tab
```