# The number of columns in PdfPTable constructor must be greater than zero

Tags: c#, gridview, itext

```
protected void pdf(DataTable dt, string str)
        {
            Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 22, 34, 34);
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath+"sdad.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Table"));
            GridView dataGridview = new GridView();


            dataGridview.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty = true;
            dataGridview.AllowPaging = false;
            dataGridview.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridview.DataBind();
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridview.Columns.Count);
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridview.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridview.Columns[j].HeaderText));
            }
            table.HeaderRows = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridview.Rows.Count;j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridview.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (dataGridview.Rows[j].Cells[k].Text  != null)
                    {
                        table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridview.Rows[j].Cells[k].Text.ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();

        }
```

This is the code for creating a PDF using Isharp text. But I am getting error The number of columns in PdfPTable constructor must be greater than zero. Please can anyone help to solve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the value of dataGridView.Columns.Count

Comment: Actually its showing as zero. But I can see the data grid view with three columns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324598/column-count-does-not-match-in-datatable-and-databound-datagridview

Comment: Why don't you just use the DataTable instead of making a new grid view control. And how can you see it? You don't add it to any form, as far as I can see.

Comment: Ok. thanks. I will go for table . I am showing a grid view in one function and one more function for creative pdf.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had this apparently "invalid" html:

```
 <table class="table-bordered" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px">
 </table>
```

ie. A table without rows.

Comment: Bingo.. Invalid Html Format was the culprit for me

Answer (score 0):

i have faced this problem and i found the solution, you can add

`AutoGenerateColumns="False"` `ItemsSource="{Binding}` in your xml (in DataGrid tag).
 then you must specify dataGrid.Columns.

```
<DataGrid  Name="grdTransaksi" HorizontalAlignment="Left"Margin="10,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tanggal" Binding="{Binding tanggal}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kode Akun" Binding="{Binding KodeAkun}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```